# jquery when to use the .on method

Tags: jquery

I have this function:

```
$(".divbody tbody tr td").keydown(function (e) {                

            var $this = this;           

            KeyCheck($this, e);
            return false;

});
```

Basically, I am attaching the keydown event to cells in my table (to use the arrow key for navigation) .divBody is the class name of table.  It is working as expected.

1) Is this the correct way to attach a handler to the cells?

2) I am confused on when I should use the .on method.  Should I avoid the above and use the below instead:

```
$( ".divbody" ).on( "keydown", "tbody tr td", function(e) {  

            var $this = this;           

            KeyCheck($this, e);
            return false;

        });
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: `.on` is available for the more recent versions of jquery... it didn't used to have that.  I always use it because it makes more sense to me..?

Comment: yes, but why should I use .on() method?

Comment: The second version of `.on()` is used for event delegation.

Comment: Nope, not using contentedotable attribute

Comment: do I need event delegation?  would the first example suffice?

Comment: @undefined is right... that's why it's awesome.  so your `tbody tr td` can be applied to dynamic content within your div. (ajax loaded stuff)  liiike... if you wanted to add table rows with buttons on the fly.  the js won't work for them unless you do it like that with the `.on` delegation on an element that is not dynamic.

Comment: You need something when you really need it, if the first code works for you, no, you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.on` event binds the listener in such a way that if you add an element to the `document`, it will still fire.  If you add it to the objects like the first example, it will only bind to existing elements such that if you add new elements, it will not fire for them.

So, the question of which one to use comes down to whether or not you will be adding new `td`s to the `table` and if you will need to handle keydown for them.  If you are not, you don't need to be able to add new `td`s, using the first option will perform slightly better overall.

Comment: Great! that answered it!

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, youre using event delegation.  Any `td` element child of `.divbody` will call your handler.

It's similar to how `live` worked, meaning future child elements not yet created will still have the handled event fired.

see http://api.jquery.com/on/

for example,

```
$(".mytable td").click(function(e) { alert('cell clicked'); });
```

would only be set as the handler for elements that already exist.

```
$(".mytable").on('click','td', function(e) {alert('cell clicked'); });
```

would fire for td elements yet to be added to the dom

if however all your elements are already in the dom, you can stick to your first example.